# Catch2 installation on ubuntu 20.04 #include <catch2/catch.hpp>

Tags: c++, cmake, catch2

I am trying to install [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) on ubuntu 20.04.

Used instruction from [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/cmake-integration.md).

This is what i do:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
$ cd Catch2
$ cmake -Bbuild -H. -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF
$ sudo cmake --build build/ --target install
```

Than it saing me that all ok: [link for output](https://pastebin.com/cwLF9bAS).

BUT:
When I try to compile the example: // [from here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/benchmarks.md)

main.cpp

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN  // This tells Catch to provide a main() - only do this in one cpp file
#define CATCH_CONFIG_ENABLE_BENCHMARKING
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>


std::uint64_t Fibonacci(std::uint64_t number) {
    return number < 2 ? 1 : Fibonacci(number - 1) + Fibonacci(number - 2);
}

TEST_CASE("Fibonacci") {
    CHECK(Fibonacci(0) == 1);
    // some more asserts..
    CHECK(Fibonacci(5) == 8);
    // some more asserts..

    // now let's benchmark:
    BENCHMARK("Fibonacci 20") {
        return Fibonacci(20);
    };

    BENCHMARK("Fibonacci 25") {
        return Fibonacci(25);
    };

    BENCHMARK("Fibonacci 30") {
        return Fibonacci(30);
    };

    BENCHMARK("Fibonacci 35") {
        return Fibonacci(35);
    };
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Persistent-world LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Catch2::Catch2)
```

It output such ERROR: **catch2/catch.hpp: No such file or directory**

Thanks in advance

[image: Error]

Comment: I understand that there is no file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is quite simple: clonning catchorg/Catch2 now gets you a v3 branch by default, which works differently. The most important change is that it is no longer single header, and that the `catch2/catch.hpp` header no longer exists.

You can either switch to the v2 branch before configuring and installing the build, or adapt your code to the changes in v3, [starting with this documentation on v2 -> v3 migration](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/migrate-v2-to-v3.md#top).

To get the default main, link against `Catch2::Catch2WithMain` target.

Answer (score 5):

Admin helped me.

On catch v3. I need:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Catch2 LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )
find_package(Catch2)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Catch2::Catch2WithMain)
```

If you just link against Catch2::Catch2, you won't get the default main and have to write your own, and your own main needs to invoke the tests. See e.g. [that](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/own-main.md#let-catch-take-full-control-of-args-and-config)

Than i understand that with main it should looks like:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN  // This tells Catch to provide a main() - only do this in one cpp file
#define CATCH_CONFIG_ENABLE_BENCHMARKING
#include <catch2/catch_all.hpp>

std::uint64_t Fibonacci(std::uint64_t number) {
    return number < 2 ? 1 : Fibonacci(number - 1) + Fibonacci(number - 2);
}

TEST_CASE("Fibonacci") {
    CHECK(Fibonacci(0) == 1);
    // some more asserts..
    CHECK(Fibonacci(5) == 8);
    // some more asserts..

    // now let's benchmark:
    BENCHMARK("Fibonacci 20") {
        return Fibonacci(20);
    };

    BENCHMARK("Fibonacci 25") {
        return Fibonacci(25);
    };

    BENCHMARK("Fibonacci 30") {
        return Fibonacci(30);
    };

    BENCHMARK("Fibonacci 35") {
        return Fibonacci(35);
    };
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Catch::Session session; // There must be exactly one instance

  // writing to session.configData() here sets defaults
  // this is the preferred way to set them

  int returnCode = session.applyCommandLine( argc, argv );
  if( returnCode != 0 ) // Indicates a command line error
        return returnCode;

  // writing to session.configData() or session.Config() here
  // overrides command line args
  // only do this if you know you need to

  int numFailed = session.run();

  // numFailed is clamped to 255 as some unices only use the lower 8 bits.
  // This clamping has already been applied, so just return it here
  // You can also do any post run clean-up here
  return numFailed;
}
```

[image: output]